# Use BETWEEN AND Clause in Yii QueryBuilder

Tags: php, yii

This code is not working as it should work i want to check period_id between start and end period using between and clause but not able to do how

```
$return = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                            ->select('period_id')
                            ->from('SCHOOL_PERIODS')
                            ->where('school_id=:school_id', array(':school_id'=>$schoolId))
                            ->andWhere('syear=:syear', array(':syear'=>$schoolYear))
                            ->andWhere('ignore_scheduling IS NULL')
                            ->andWhere('period_id>:start', array(':start' => $startPeriod))
                            ->andWhere('period_id<:end', array(':end' => $maxPeriod))
                            ->order('sort_order asc')
                            ->queryAll();
        return $return;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334072/yii-criteria-condition-between-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting a space before and after the angle bracket like so

```
period_id > :start
```

If this still does not work, remove the two lines

```
->andWhere('period_id>:start', array(':start' => $startPeriod))
->andWhere('period_id<:end', array(':end' => $maxPeriod))
```

Then use the following instead

```
->andWhere('period_id > :start AND period_id < :end', array(':start' => $startPeriod',':end' => $maxPeriod))
```

If you then want to use HAVING, add this line underneath your grouping. This will mean you can use values form another query you have already run.

```
->having('period_id > :resultfromOtherQueryStart AND period_id:resultFromOtherQueryEnd',array(':resultFromOtherQuery'=>$otherQueryStart,':otherQueryEnd'=>$otherQueryEnd))
```

Comment: @OmShanker no worries. Yii rules

Comment: Paul one more thing. Now i want to use HAVING Clause which will get its values from another query say for example: ->having("select ...). now how to achieve this