# check if one table's date overlaps with another table's in yii

Tags: yii

I have two tables (A and B) that don't have relations with each other. (I guess their relations would be a product id, which is in another table (table C)??) A and B both have a from and to date. I don't want the user to submit overlapping dates within these two tables. So if table A has a date from 3/1 to 6/1, table B shouldn't have anything between those two dates or overlapping dates. Is there a way to check this in the validation?

I have something like this, but it just submits every single time, while I'm looking for that error.

```
public function tableADateExists($attribute, $params)
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;    
    $a = new tableA();

    $criteria->compare('product_id',$this->main_pid,true,'OR');
    $criteria->compare('product_id',$this->target_pid,true,'OR');
    //product_id in table A
    $criteria->addBetweenCondition('start_date', $this->effective_from_date, $this->effective_to_date, 'OR');
    $criteria->addBetweenCondition('end_date', $this->effective_from_date, $this->effective_to_date);
    //start_date and end_date in table A, the other in table B
    $model = $a->exists($criteria);
    if (!empty($model)) {
        $this->addError($attribute, "Item already exists in period.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I asked a similar question, see if that helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334072/yii-criteria-condition-between-date

Comment: are those two tables related? looks like they are?